# Preference Page in Eclipse e4 RCP

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, preferences, e4

I'd like to create a preferences page on my e4 pure-RCP application (no Workbench involved).
I've looked into Vogella's blogs and only found references to re-using the e3 preference page.
Please note that I'm interested only in the UI, while the storage is already managed.
How can I re-use the preference page in e4?
Thanks, regards

Comment: not sure why the negative marks... the correct answer (below) is that you can't reuse the standard preference page as you would in e3, which is exactly what my researches showed. You need to use jface APIs which is a completely different matter.

Comment: I think perhaps some voters don't realize the big differences in a pure e4 application and the almost complete lack of documentation on how to do things!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the JFace `org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog`, `PreferencePage`, `PreferenceNode` and `PreferenceManager` classes (anything in JFace).

You can't use the `org.eclipse.ui.preferencePages` extension point so you will to define your own way of managing the pages (perhaps with a similar extension point).

Comment: There is a project which does exactly this - handle e4 preference pages similar to e3 with owned extension point. 
https://github.com/opcoach/e4Preferences